# MySqlException: Duplicate entry for key 'aspnetusers.PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When trying to register a user, it says that the primary key is duplicated, which is not true.

It is a project in asp.net core and entity framework core with individual account authentication.

Video https://1drv.ms/v/s!AgN4j7ZVXF5IhQ9cZeQAQrasm7SS

Database script and code
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgN4j7ZVXF5IhQx8bUUvqkQOIicz?e=ih063u

[Img error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rG3w.png)

Comment: Don't ask us to go trawling around the web, watching videos and downloading your project code just to see what your problem is. Post the relevant code here, along with any sample data that might be pertinent. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can set this when creating a model:

1. Decorate your id propertie with the following Attributes (DatabaseGenerated...).

   ```
       ​public class Sites

                {
                    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

                    public int SiteID { get; set; }

                    public string Name { get; set; }
                       ............
                }
   ```
2. Or do it using the ModelBuilder in your DbContext.

```
public class CMSModels : DbContext
    {
    
      public DbSet<Sites> Site { get; set; }
   
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
          modelBuilder.Entity<Sites>().Property(r => r.SiteID) 
                       .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
      }
    }
```

3.Using AUTO_INCREMENT:The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```